# Problem with using Html.RenderPartial() in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a user control which accepts an 'Id' from the page where it is embedded. I used the following code to display " <% Html.RenderPartial("ViewUserControl3", Model.Guid); %>" to display the user control with specific id on the page. Any one please help me How to get that Guid in my usercontrol page and display the user control on the page where it is called.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ViewUserControl3` should be strongly typed to `Guid` and then simply use this model:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Guid>" %>

<div><%= Model %></div>
```